# PHP Sanitise $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with a Global Find and Replace How safe is it?

Tags: php, security, legacy-code

I am working on PHP based large legacy application written 15+ years ago, In order to secure the application i have sanitise the $_SERVER variables uses in the code, this has to be done with a Find and Replace command due to the large code-base that its not possible to do them one by one manually.

For example i have below variable in a php file

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>&format=excel" title="Export this report">
```

Which i am going sanitise it with a Find and Replace function to be like below

```
<a href="<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)?>&format=excel" title="Export this report">
```

My questions regarding this solution are

1. Is it safe and reliable to do this find and replace in context of a
   web-application without any nasty surprises for the end user (i.e
   Will it break the application for a legitimate use in a common case
   ? )
2. Is doing this type sanitation is considered secure ? (i.e Do we gain anything out of this filter with regard to the security of the
   application or is it just not enough to prevent any attacks)
3. Do you have any suggestion on how to improve the security of this case, keeping in mind these are old large legacy application that
   cannot be manually edit/test one by one?

Comment: Instead of doing this in place (and hoping that you find all places to begin with), I would overwrite `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with the sanitized value during the initialization phase ...

Comment: @CBroe Its legacy app, file by file base with many includes, hard to find a initialise place in the application it self.

Comment: If it doesn't have one central entry point - like an index.php that handles all routing, and then includes different files - then https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file could also be an option.

Comment: @CBroe I wish they were, very old app over 15+ years, works on form post/request file by file basis.

Comment: Well, then the second option should still work.